# query ok on select but not as a view

Tags: mysql, view

I have a query that gives the correct results as a select query but when i use it as a view it creates the view but browsing the view gives an error "Subquery returns more than 1 row". The query takes the field "meta_key" on "my_postmeta_table" table, and make it a column name for the "meta_value" field of the current row. it makes something like this:

this is the format on the table:

```
post_id  meta_key  meta_value
1        key1      val1
1        key2      val2   
2        key1      val3
2        key2      val4
```

the select query returns resaults that looks like this:

```
post_id  key1  key2
1        val1  val2
2        val3  val4
```

this is the query:

```
create or REPLACE view contacts2 as select
    post_id pid, 
    post_date Date, 
    (SELECT  meta_value from my_postmeta_table where meta_key="contact_country" and post_id=pid)  AS "Country", 
    (SELECT  meta_value from my_postmeta_table where meta_key="contact_usa_states" and post_id=pid)  AS "USA State",  
    (SELECT  meta_value from my_postmeta_table where meta_key="contact_subject" and post_id=pid)  AS "Subject",  
    (SELECT meta_value from my_postmeta_table where meta_key="contact_first_name"  and post_id=pid)  AS "First Name",  
    (SELECT meta_value from my_postmeta_table where meta_key="contact_last_name"  and post_id=pid)  AS "Last Name",  
    (SELECT meta_value from my_postmeta_table where meta_key="contact_company"  and post_id=pid)  AS "Company",  
    (SELECT meta_value from my_postmeta_table where meta_key="contact_position"  and post_id=pid)  AS "Position",  
    (SELECT meta_value from my_postmeta_table where meta_key="contact_email"  and post_id=pid)  AS "Email",  
    (SELECT meta_value from my_postmeta_table where meta_key="contact_message"  and post_id=pid)  AS "Message" 
    from my_postmeta_table, my_posts_table where my_posts_table.ID=my_postmeta_table.post_id and my_posts_table.post_type="contact"  GROUP by post_id;
```

so...if i omit this "create or REPLACE view contacts2 as" from the code above it gives good resaults.

Thank you

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Try adding a limit 1 to all subqueries.

Comment: 1. You are not clear. What does "gives the correct results" mean? Or "use it as a view"? Or "browsing the view", or "good result"? Besides using words to explain what you are doing and have done, explain situations exactly per [mcve] per the first comment above. 2. Read about proper use of [SELECT with GROUP BY, and MySQL's  ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html). Don't use a column in a SELECT outside an aggregate if it wasn't in the GROUP BY or single-valued per the GROUP BY columns.

Comment: @Shadow The error message goes away, so the answer must be correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you expect all the subqueries to return only 1 record, then just add `limit 1` to the end of each subquery. This way mysql will know that the subqueries will definitely return 1 record only.